# mysql pdo issues with bindings

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

new to PDO, so i dont know much, but learning.

i am just playing about with the bindings in PDO, and i dont seem to be able to get them to work

here is working code:

```
$prepare = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'admin'");
$prepare->execute();
print_r($prepare->fetch());
```

now i wish to use bindings, and replace the admin part:
i have this, and its not working (banging my head on the wall didn't help)

```
$prepare = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ':user'");
$prepare->execute(array(':user' => "admin"));
print_r($prepare->fetch());
```

where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be without single quotes,

```
$prepare = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :user");
$prepare->execute(array('user' => "admin"));
print_r($prepare->fetch());
```

Great [tutorials](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#71929) are already available on php site on pdo.